# PHP :Fatal error Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql

I have this Code For Insert `timestamp` into mySql database(`i need to this for customize`):

```
$datepub = $_POST['datepub'];
$timepub = $_POST['timepub'];
$timedate = $datepub .''.$timepub;
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d h:i:s', $timedate);
$month = $datetime->format('m'); // Line 61
$year  = $datetime->format('Y');
$date  = $datetime->format('d');
$hour = $datetime->format('h');
$minute  = $datetime->format('i');
$sec  = $datetime->format('s');
```

But I see This error :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\modules\add.php on line 61
```

when i `echo $timedate` output is : 2014/03/1516:45:30

How do can i fix this error?

Comment: What is the value of $datepub and $timepub?

Comment: try Y/m/d H:i:s instead of Y/m/d h:i:s and yes a white space is missing during concatenation

Comment: `$datepub:2014/03/15`  and `$timepub:16:45:30`

Comment: @SandeepRajoria: You right. This Worked now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct as follows:

```
$timedate = $datepub .' '.$timepub;//add a space
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d H:i:s', $timedate); //need capital H
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a white space. This line:

```
$timedate = $datepub .''.$timepub;
```

should be:

```
$timedate = $datepub . ' ' . $timepub;
```